# Search arabic text while ignoring diacritics or accents

Tags: ios, swift, arabic

Search feature works fine when I use the Arabic with the vowels (fatha, kasra, etc.).  How can I search the Arabic text while being vowels/accents insensitive?

For example, if I search for واليوم  it should display all results like وَالْيَوْمِ

This is the code I use with vowels (diacritics).

```
 let arabicMatch = Dua.arabic.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
```

For swift and iOS 9.

Comment: This is called text normalization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSStringCompareOptions` also has a `DiacriticInsensitiveSearch` you can use (in the same way as the case insensitive).

Comment: I just replace it with DiacriticInsensitiveSearch.  Do I still need the CaseInsensitiveSearch?

Comment: that's a question about your requirements, you can include both if you need them both

Answer (score 0):

or you can make normalize string

```
extension String {

func normalizeArabic() -> String {
    let newString = NSMutableString(string: self) as CFMutableString
    CFStringTransform(newString, nil, kCFStringTransformLatinArabic, Bool(truncating: 0))
    CFStringTransform(newString, nil, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, Bool(truncating: 0))
    return newString as String
}}
```